# slow performance of outlook addin to get contact item for distribution list

Tags: c#, performance, outlook, visual-studio-addins

I have the following code it takes lot of time to retrieve contact items from the distribution list, exchange server. Is there anything can be done to tune it s performance

> ```
> public Outlook.AddressEntry GetDistributionListMembers(string sParamName,Outlook.Application _OutlookApp)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             List<string> allAddressEntriesList = new List<string>();
>             Outlook.AddressLists addrLists = _OutlookApp.ActiveExplorer().Session.AddressLists;
>             var receipientContactList = new List<Outlook.AddressEntry>();
>             foreach (Outlook.AddressList addrList in addrLists)
>             {
>                 if (addrList.AddressEntries.Count <= 0) continue;
>                 receipientContactList.AddRange(addrList.AddressEntries.Cast<Outlook.AddressEntry>()
>                     .Where(x => x.Address.ToLower().Equals(sParamName.ToLower())));
> ```
>
> ## if debug
>
> ```
>                  Debug.print(addrList.Name);
> ```
>
> ## endif
>
> ```
>                 if (receipientContactList.Count > 0) break;
>             }
>             return receipientContactList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetContact().HasPicture) ??
>                    receipientContactList.FirstOrDefault();
>
>         }
>         catch (System.Exception ex)
>         {
>             WriteLog(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name,
> ```
>
> ex.Message);
>                   return null;
>               }
>
> ```
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, never loop through all entries in the address book. You are matching on an address; why not use `Namespace.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve`?

Secondly, you are assuming that all address entries come from your Contacts folder. In case of GAL under Exchange, this is not the case, and `AddressEntry.GetContact()` will return null, resulting in an exception.

And if your entries always come from the Contacts folder, why not use `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)` and then use `MAPIFolder.Items.Find`?

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I need to search contactitem from local address entry and also GAL and all available address list entries in local outlook instance. I need to be checking if contact item is distributionlist, or individual and depending on that data to be displayed. Do you have any references/links to look at ? Many thanks

Comment: Thanks I have resolved it by checking oAddressEntry.Type == "EX" or oAddressEntry.Type == "SMTP". Can you please let me know how to find if the sender/recpient is a distribution list and get count if the number of email accounts associated with it. thanks

Comment: Check is AddressEntry.Members is not null and then check Members.Count